# Eonasdan Datetimepicker - how manipulate date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I wanted to ask, how can i manipulate data in Javascript, to have data like this in datetime input:

From 2015.10.12

Not as default:

2015.10.12.

Here is my code, You will see format option for date formatting, but this is wrong idea:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        locale: 'en',
        format: 'FROM' + 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    });
```

I am building form with 2 inputs, From and To, and when user selects some date, i wanted to show him not just date, but also this info.

Thank You for help.

Answer (score 0):

This code will allow for custom text.
    format: '[AB] YYYY-MM-DD'.Needed to add brackets [].